How can I code synchronous programs in Node?
I'm a career programmer, very comfortable writing programs in Python, and recently started learning Node.
I understand the asynchronous features are useful in many situations, but when I debug my code, I find myself adding await before every single statement (including debug log statements), to be absolutely sure the program is doing what I expect, and is outputting logs in the order I expect so that I can see what is happening.
I always want my code to execute synchronously. Is there a better way to achieve this than adding await at the start of every line?

Some of the APIs have synchronous versions, e.g. https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#synchronous-example. You don't need to await things that don't return promises, but doing so isn't a major problem (details: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55262996/3001761).

This stack overflow Q/A should help...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775262/synchronous-requests-in-node-js

"I always want my code to execute synchronously", well, you need to change your mindset, because you can't do that. Not with JavaScript anyway. Yes, synchronous APIs exist, but these literally make JavaScript single threaded without any support for concurrency. So don't use them, it is shooting yourself in foot. await is the closest thing to synchronous execution you will get.

I have to agree with the OP. This person could use some help clearing up some misconceptions. Rather than down-voting, consider posting an answer.

Coding synchronously or asynchronously is determined by the deepest function call in a call stack, to put it naively. Callers don't determine if code runs synchronously. The authors of the functions you call determine this by marking the function async and returning Promise objects. The downstream affect is best described in What Color is Your Function? As soon as your function needs to call something asynchronously, your function needs to be marked async, because it must return a Promise. Now anyone calling your function needs to handle this change in function signature.
So, the way to program synchronously is to not call async functions.
Promises in JavaScript do give you a way out of this mess. You can invoke the .then() callback on the promise. Your function will not be async, but it will also not be synchronous. JavaScript is full of these weird situations.
Consider these two code snippets:
Using Async and Await
async function calculate(num) {
    let result = await someFunction();
    let total = num * result.multiplier;

    return total;
}

let sumTotal = await calculate(4);

alert("sum total is: " + sumTotal);

The await keyword spreads everywhere, but each async function call is a clean one-liner. Compare that to code which uses promises, but does not use await:
let sumTotal = 0;

calculate(4).then(result => {
    sumTotal = result;

    alert("sum total is: " + sumTotal);
});

You start building nested callbacks to Promise.then(). The second example uses synchronous code, but still executes asynchronously. You just can't seem to escape the asynchronous part. More vexingly, beware that the result of your promise can be available independently of when you want to use that result. Consider this code:
Using Promises and Callbacks
let sumTotal = 0;

calculate(4).then(result => {
    sumTotal = result;
});

// Alerts "sum total is 0"
alert("sum total is: " + sumTotal);

Race conditions can make your code execute out of order. In the code above, you could get sum total is 0 or sum total is 552 depending on how fast the promise is resolved from the calculate function.
GeeksForGeeks.org has a good comparison of the two ways to call functions. Even though it is geared towards the NodeJS runtime, it applies equally to web browsers:



Promise
Async/Await




Promise is an object representing intermediate state of operation which is guaranteed to complete its execution at some point in future.
Async/Await is a syntactic sugar for promises, a wrapper making the code execute more synchronously.


Promise has 3 states – resolved, rejected and pending.
It does not have any states. It returns a promise either resolved or rejected.


If the function “fxn1” is to executed after the promise, then promise.then(fxn1) continues execution of the current function after adding the fxn1 call to the callback chain.
If the function “fxn1” is to executed after await, then await X() suspends execution of the current function and then fxn1 is executed.


Error handling is done using .then() and .catch() methods.
Error handling is done using .try() and .catch() methods.


Promise chains can become difficult to understand sometimes.
Using Async/Await makes it easier to read and understand the flow of the program as compared to promise chains.



Source: Difference between Promise and async/await in Node | GeeksForGeeks.org
Strictly writing synchronous code means avoiding calling async functions or functions that return promises, otherwise you are stuck with asynchronous code one way or the other.
